# Software for class scheduling

Tags: time-management, scheduling

I have to arrange students and teachers into classes with different constraints. Is there any software that can automate the process and yet is flexible in defining constraints?

EDIT:
Some trivial constraints:

A student has one class at a time
A teacher goes to one class at a time
A teacher attends in specified days.

My OS is either Linux or Windows.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Could you please [edit] your question and add a few more details concerning your requirements – e.g. what OS is shall run on, do you need a GUI, what kind of "automation" is expected (that might be your constraints, or other things)? For a guide, please see: [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185)

Comment: And **look at what you write** (layout)! Your edit made an unreadable mess of your question. I cleaned it up. It is in your interest to write good questions that people will take time to read and answer.

Comment: The question still looks incomplete: You want the software to be *flexible in defining constraints*, and then you give only trivial constraints...

Comment: Ok, In fact my requirements are changing year by year (based on the department rules), and I'm not sure if they would be trivial in the next year! By the way, consider flexibility as a positive point to suggest please.